# Matlab showing blank screen when I connect remotely with xrdp in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, matlab, xrdp

If I use my CentOS 7 computer everything works fine but when I connect remotely (I have tried connecting from Ubuntu and Windows xrdp clients) everything works fine too except Matlab which shows a blank screen.

[image]

It is a visual bug because I click on the blank screen and It does stuff. I can't understand why this only happens when connecting remotely. I have tried using gnome and xfce desktop environments and nothing changes.

Also I have other Ubuntu computers which I connect remotely and Matlab works fine there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the colors depth of the remote session to High Color (16 bit) fixes it.
[Link](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/5610061)

In windows using the default RDP client was enough, in Kubuntu I had to use Remmina, with KRDC it didn't work, even changing to 16 bits color